# 2015 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, election

Movies & TV's [1st moderator election](https://movies.stackexchange.com//election/1) has come to a close, the votes have been tallied, and the 3 new moderators are:

[image: iandotkelly] [image: Napoleon Wilson] [image: Ankit Sharma]

Please thank them for volunteering, and share your assistance and advice with them as they learn the ropes!

Also, join me in thanking the outgoing [*pro tempore* moderator team](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/216/moderator-pro-tem-announcement).

For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results [here](https://movies.stackexchange.com//election/1), or [view a summary report online](http://www.opavote.org/results/5414448458104832/0).

Comment: Congratulations!

Comment: Nice job, everyone!

Comment: Good luck moving forward you guys!

Comment: Congrats to Ankit and Napoleon ... Ian, you were a shoe-in! The results were not surprising ;-)

Comment: Kudos and a huge thanks to the mod squad and to everyone who voted!

Comment: Congratulations!!! && Napoleon Wilson lost all his hair after elections!!

Comment: Great to see Ankit as mod.. looking forward for your commitment :)

Comment: Congratulations folks! Don't be evil and enjoy yourselves :) * *bows to new overlords* *

Comment: Gosh look at the little shiny diamond by your name too. I'm proper jelly now.

Comment: New look! New mods! Congratulations!

Comment: Congrats guys!  I love forward to seeing this community grow even more.

Comment: Better ingredients, better moderators, papa johns(I mean Movies and TV SE)!  Congrats guys!

Comment: Congrats Ankit Sharma you were very persistent in the previous year. you really deserve the spot.

Answer (score 14):

[image: I voted for Kodos]

Seriously, though, congrats to our new <strike>overlords</strike> mods.