# 365 days out of beta: Where do we stand?

Tags: discussion, site-evaluation, graduation

As you might have noticed, this site [graduated about a year ago](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1521/49). This might be the right time to look back at the previous year, or even the whole site lifetime, and see how we are doing. This is a follow up to all the [previous questions of this kind](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aquestion+where+do+we+stand), just this time asking *us* instead of SE (though, avid SE employees are of course encouraged to share some input, too) and the cancelled [community self-evaluations](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/site-evaluation), just broader and more subjective.

So please **share all your thoughts about this site's and its community's current situation, its history and its prospects**, be they positive or negative, situational or developmental, be they just statements or even proposals for what we could change or improve (from which individual meta discussions could then be spawned). Really any kind of laudatio or constructive criticism is welcome, just tell us what you think about the site and maybe where you'd like to see it go.

- What are we doing great?
- What could we do better?
- What improved since public beta?
- Has anything gotten worse last year?
- What could we do differently?
- Is there any trend you're dissatisfied with?
- ...

In addition to the new design, this site also held [democratic moderator elections](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1646/49) nearly a year ago. So in addition to the site and its community itself, also feel free to adress **any constructive criticism towards the current moderator team**. What could we do better? Where is room for improvement? In which aspects of the site would you like to see more (or even less) moderator involvement?

Answer (score 25):

I'm going to come right out and say it. As someone who has been an active member for almost precisely a year (I got my 2nd Yearling badge yesterday), this site *feels* like it's still in a Beta stage. There's some good, but there's also some bad and some downright ugly that we need to have a hard think about.

### The Good

- The overall volume of questions is ***[increasing](https://data.stackexchange.com/movies/query/76893/questions-statistics)***. If nothing else, that suggests that even if we ignore everything below this sentence and **do nothing at all** (always a serious, but oft overlooked option), we can probably grow our way out of trouble if we **just wait**.

[image]

- **The general quality of answers** *feels* reasonably high, especially from power users like Walt. I very rarely need to use comments point out the inadequacies in people's answers, nor do I go away from the site shaking my head and wondering what people were smoking when they started typing.
- **Spam and abusive questions** are dealt with quickly and efficiently (yay us, yay moderators)
- **Duplicates** seem to be dealt with very efficiently where they occur (again, yay us).

### The Bad

- **So. Very. Many. Ident. Questions.**
  Don't get me wrong, I like ident questions. I do. Really I do. But there's just so bloody many of them and they're almost all really really crappy and vague. On top of that, the titles are almost uniformly bad. Updating the close script has made me more comfortable about flagging them for closure and I do my personal best to edit as many as I can to try to make them workable, but it feels like trying to bale out the hoover dam.
- **Moderation team**
  One of the site's [moderators](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) seems to be AWOL. That's all I'm saying on the issue. Discuss.
- **The Walt show.**
  I like [Walt](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users/4386/walt). I like his answers. I like that his answers are prompt and well-referenced. I don't even mind that he keeps beating me to answers. That being said, there's a hard-core of prolific answerers (headed up by Walt) that are ***everywhere***. I've noticed that when they answer, other people don't. I've investigated this same effect on another stack and the conclusion I drew was that when one of the site's high-rep users come along and answer questions, it heavily deters anyone else from doing so, especially lower rep users. This then potentially detracts from new users interacting on the site if they can't have easy wins. Note that this isn't their fault and they **absolutely shouldn't stop**. It's just something we need to think about as a community.

### The ugly

- Did I already mention ident questions?
- **Lack of community involvement in Meta**
  The number of meta answers (and votes) seems worryingly low to me. Even issues like close-reasons (which should be hotly contested) only get a few votes either way. You can't build a concensus when there's a hard-core of users expressing their views, largely as a bloc
- **Lack of site voting and praise, especially for new users**
  This one is a toughie, but since day one I've been complaining that we (as a community) simply don't do enough to reward older answers with upvotes and praise. A few encouraging comments and an upvote go a very very long way.
- **Site look/feel**
  This is purely a personal gripe, but the site is downright **ugly** to look at. The red banners give me eyestrain and the white on white borders are painful to view for any amount of time. If this site was a child, it would need to tie a piece of steak around its neck to get the dog to play with it. And yes, I know that I could load scripts to make it look less unpleasant but that's hardly something that a new visitor would necessarily want to do if they didn't like it.

Comment: Very insightful answers (and I'm especially suprised about the second point) and I can share many of your points and concerns **apart from the last one, the site design is friggin' awesome!** (and I'm honestly struggling with voting this up just because of that point, especially since it implies that new users generally think so, too, when it's nothing but an entirely subjective assessment). ;-P

Comment: @NapoleonWilson - I'm sorry, but the design is one step away from [flashing text and dancing banana gifs](http://web.archive.org/web/20070208064230/http://www.americanbeautybordercollies.com/)

Comment: I see your point on some of these.  I don't agree with you on the point about Walt.  I don't think it is fair to single him out for providing great answers.  That is like punishing him for being a valued member of the community.  Are you saying that Walt himself is a "Monopoly"?  He was a new user once and had to learn how to navigate this site like all new users.  You know that I have your back on most things, just not on this particular point :)

Comment: +1, despite a few points of contention (namely the ones mentioned in the comments). Couple of notes: 1. You shouldn't have started with the graph, I kept getting distracted by the question, *"What the hell happened in mid-May?!"* ;) 2. I really hope no one thinks my A's are the final word about *any* Q (even ID ones, where I'm sometimes wrong); *I* sure don't. But just to make it official: *They aren't*, not even remotely. I may have been around too much (I'm trying to cut down), but like steelerfan said, we can't really fault people for over-contributing. I'll never fault *you* for it.

Comment: (Anyway, great response. I'll comment a bit more about ID on Andrew's answer. BTW, what did you mean by white on white? I didn't quite get that.)

Comment: @Walt - Black text on a white background with white borders and nothing to distinguish the edge of the text can be quite grating, especially for those of us with widescreen monitors. http://i.stack.imgur.com/xqGEE.png

Comment: @Walt - The issue isn't that you're contributing too much, it's that others aren't contributing enough. The good thing is that as the number of questions rises, even a prolific poster will eventually be overwhelmed by the sheer volume of questions that can be answered. I gather SFF:SE went through much the same learning curve with DVK swamping the site to begin with, then simply becoming one high-activity poster among many.

Comment: I'd be delighted to be overwhelmed by anything positive, sure. ;)

Comment: [text & colors] Hmm, I guess it never bothered me. Are you sure this issue is exclusive to M&TV, or is it more of a general SE issue?

Comment: @Walt - Less of an issue on SFF:SE. The borders are white on blue, with a heavy blue border to delineate the edge of the text

Comment: I'm not sure I would consider "That being said, there's a hard-core of prolific answerers (headed up by Walt) that are everywhere." as necessarily bad *per-se*. One could argue that you, Thaddeus, and DVK made up exactly such a set of prolific answerers on SF&F and all it seemed to do was encourage other users to try and match you. I think the real question is, why *isn't* that happening here?

Comment: @MikeEdenfield - I'd argue that even at my height, I was still only answering an *average* of 4-5 questions per day. When there are 20-30+ each day, the still represents a sizeable share but plenty for everyone. By comparison, if there are only 10(ish) questions per day, then 5 answers represents half.

Comment: Yeah, but what does it matter if Walt chooses to answer all of the questions posted in a day?  Shouldn't that be his choice?  I can somewhat understand if he was taking a bullying stance, for lack of a better term, but he welcomes other answers and his quality of answers only challenge other users to rise to a level of excellence.  Next thing you know, users are going to start getting participation "trophies" for simply being on the team with no valid contributions whatsoever ;)

Comment: @steelerfan - I see it as a problem because a very small number of users are consuming a very sizeable proportion of the answerable questions each day. Since we can't ask users to answer less (it wouldn't be appropriate or fair), there are only two solutions - Get more questions and/or encourage other users to answer more often.

Comment: I see your point, but Walt is one of the instigators for that.  He is always encouraging another answer along with his.  Granted, it's done in chat, but users should strive for excellence from his answers rather than not participate at all.  Again, Walt should not be faulted for setting a high standard.  I mean, if we're talking about "fair", it's not fair to single Walt out for setting a standard of excellence.

Comment: @steelerfan - A vanishingly small number of users every use chat, or are even aware of it. Probably less than .5% of all site users have visited even once and probably less than .01% of new users.

Comment: I get that, I do.  But,  users need to take it upon themselves to navigate through the site and see what's available.  I spent a lot of time reading highly voted Q and A's along with asking questions in chat.  Nobody told me to do that, I took it upon myself to do that because I was interested in the site and I wanted to learn about it.  There is a tutorial available for new users.  While established users should encourage new users, it's up to the new user to take the next step.

Comment: I don't think, particularly recently, that Walt is answering all of the answers... for the last two months, he's averaged only 3 or so answers per day... and when he was answering more questions, they were largely ID questions, which I'm personally not disappointed that he's handling... someone should (if we're going to allow them)... and a lot of users don't like them, or ignore them outright. Walt also gives back a lot to the community, regularly giving bounties to worthy answers he sees...

Comment: @Walt, I am a new user *to this particular SE* and this comment is in fact my first post in M&TV. The evolution & dynamics of SE (and of volunteer organizations of all kinds) is a personal fascination of mine and so I was intrigued by the Meta Q on the sidebar. I have absolutely no right to ask this but I will ask it anyways to gather *your* view on the matter.  - - - - - but it won't fit on one comment so please see the next one!

Comment: @Walt (continued) Assuming that Napoleon *might* be correct in his assessment that others back off when you answer a Q -- just because you really are that good dude -- would you be willing to voluntarily put yourself on a "delay circuit" and wait 24-48 hours before jumping into the mix on new questions? Not permanently, just for maybe 60 days, to see if that helps improve participation by others and increases the number of active users providing answers here. What do you think ?

Comment: Hi @O.M.Y. and thanks for the input (and welcome to M&TV!). It's actually Richard who wrote that, not Napoleon, but as for the suggestion: I don't think it would be fair to deny people answers just to test a theory that I think is incorrect (and that we can't even gauge in any way). And as I explained on chat the other day, *I'd be a pretty bad example for this effect anyway*. I mostly answer ID Qs, where one correct answer is all that's needed, and plenty of the non-ID Qs I answered had other good answers, sometimes ranking higher than mine. So I don't see the point in this.

Comment: @O.M.Y.  ...However, *this may naturally happen anyway.* ;) I've been working around the clock in the last couple of weeks and my levels of participation here are unfortunately already lower that usual. So if you believe this has any effect on other answers, maybe you'll have a chance to test it after all.

Comment: I don't know, people either take Richard's remark about Walt way too seriously or he meant it really way more serious than it actually is. As Walt said himself, while he also writes great non-ID answers now and then, he's by far not the only one to do that and singling him out that way seems way out of proportion. I don't know how one actually gets such an impression, other than by really only reading ID questions, where he's indeed the king, but where multiple answers are often rather useless anyway (and which would mostly go rather unanswered without his contributions anyway).

Comment: @Walt: I'd have serious issues if you imposed a self-inflicted timeout over something like this. Just... no.

Comment: @andrewmartin - No-one sensible is suggesting that he should do that

Comment: The number of comments is somewhat daunting, I'm toying with making a specific post on the subject of the moderators to make this suggestion.  I was the only active pro-tem moderator for over a year in beta.  Now with some very active moderation happening since the election (i'm looking at you Napoleon) I've dropped out of the habit of visiting the site regularly.  I don't view the AWOL comment as anything other than fair criticism.  Would people like an opportunity to replace me as a moderator or add to the moderation team?

Comment: @iandotkelly - My understanding is that there's no reason that the resignation of a moderator would '*automatically*' trigger an election. Some sites have mods  that haven't signed in for months. I believe there even a couple of mods who've gone completely dark.

Comment: @iandotkelly - That being said, I've seen it said that having a single mod doing more than 75% of the modding isn't healthy. I can only speak from experience that you find yourself ploughing a very lonely furrow when the other site mods can't be counted on to make more than a token appearance.

Comment: That last point is very true, I found myself regularly emailing SE asking them to appoint more pro-tem moderators to be told the beta hence the election would be held 'soon'.  I don't think I can maintain anything like the activity of Napoleon, but perhaps I should make an effort to be here  more.

Comment: One of the mods on [cooking.se] has been AWOL since May... they have an election now but I don't think the infrequent visits of one out of three mods is detrimental. There's not a huge amount of bad content that needs to be dealt with, from my POV... But it's not as if Napoleon's the only mod. Ankit's usually quite active, he's simply been on vacation recently... and, honestly, Napoleon goes above and beyond, in my opinion... not complaining, but he does more than most mods on any of the sites I visit.

Comment: I suppose one down side is that, despite Napoleon's somewhat unpredictable schedule, the balance of **when** the mods are here (since Napoleon's in Europe and Ankit's in India) can mean a slight delay in dealing with issues if they occur during the odd hours they're asleep... but I don't think it's "perfect" on any site that only has three.

Comment: @catija - Again, I can only speak from my personal experience but the guiding principle behind modding on SE is that it should be a shared duty, specifically to dispel the sort of us vs them mentality that can develop

Comment: @Catija I supposed Napoleon never sleeps :D

Comment: @Richard Till now i can't see issue with it. Spam got cleared in no time, Flags are handled proper too. Review bar take bit time but its mostly same in most of SE site. Its not that Ian doesn't comes here, he just don't chat much in public room but i have seen him handling flags silently too.

Comment: On the side note, i was on holiday and have to read all stuff before this post as it was bit large. After reading you answer it felt like during eating a pastry i got fly in my mouth :D, no no upvote for now :p . Few point i completely want to ignore from you answer is The Walt show, voting and Site design, as none of them are any issue to me. Moderation team can be consider sometime but not an urgent issue now.

Comment: For the bad points , meta do need more participation but i have seen it improving too and still have space to improve and Napoleon is doing quit good in promoting meta by his posts and still need more work. ID is surely an issue and i am becoming more and more against them day by day and some decision is required for it sooner.  On the ending note, I surely loved you input and i do appreciate your work here.

Comment: The red design certainly draws a disproportionate amount of emphasis to hot questions from this site when viewed on other sites http://i.stack.imgur.com/T9uIl.png

Comment: @MartinSmith That's also because the HNQ ad background has become more boring since the 300px sidebar rework.

Comment: HNQ text font and shadow working against me.

Comment: I have a large issue with the moderator statement and believe it could be why you were removed (or asked to step down) as a moderator from SF&F, Richard. The theory of moderation for SE is actually for the moderator *to do as little as possible*. The bulk of the moderation should be done by the average Joe user, not by the mods themselves. Realistically if the moderation work was *not* getting done, you might have an argument ... but that doesn't seem so. It appears to me this site is well looked after, not only by its moderation team, but mo-betta by the constituency of users as it should be.

Comment: @ᴘᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 - There is a dramatic difference between doing "as little as possible" and not logging in for weeks at a time. As I said in another comment, the goal is for moderation work to be *shared*, or else the site can very rapidly descend into a 'me vs a particular mod" mentality. For the record, I place my downfall largely on finding out that the Community Managers (and other mods on the site) didn't have my back on high profile matters but that's a longer conversation for a different day...

Comment: I think you should go back and (re)read [A Theory of Moderation](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/) written by Jeff Atwood in 2009. It is enlightening. You don't have to be as active as Napoleon Wilson to be a good moderator ... and I'm not saying Napoleon isn't doing a good job. He definitely has style, that's for sure!

Answer (score 17):

I'm going to throw in an answer to this, even though I haven't answered or questioned on the site for many months now. I still visit this site on a daily basis. I'm not usually logged in, so it doesn’t appear that way, but I still find time in work to look at this site and the Sci Fi site multiple times a day.

I think @Richard has captured many of my feelings and thoughts on the site perfectly and I'm going to refer to some of his points throughout my own answer.

Firstly, the growth in questions is great for he metrics of the site and the quality of answers is generally very good. I also believe the site is lucky to have moderators like @Napoleon (even if one of the moderators is a little awol).

However, the biggest gripe for me is the [identify-this](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identify-this) questions. I very much used to be a power user here. I'm still the fourth highest rated user by user score. But the sheer volume of [identify-this](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identify-this) questions really put me off. Walt is incredible at answering them and I've no gripes about him whatsoever. But there were (and still are) just too many of them! When I blocked them from my feed, the number of questions on a daily basis shot down. On top of that, I never quite got beyond the fact that this site is for helping current users and building a repository of information for future users - and I've never been convinced that most of the [identify-this](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identify-this) questions actually *help* future users, as opposed to being answered once and then forgotten about.

On the Sci Fi site, there are also ident questions, but they seem complementary to the other questions being asked. Here, it feels very much like there are two question groups - ident and "other". I know a while back I ran some queries on the Stack DB to see the volumes of each, and certainly in the last couple of years the increase in ident questions was, to me, alarming for the long term health of the site.

Ultimately, the amount of ident questions definitely contributed to me stepping away for a while (although I do hope to return soon) and I'll be honest and say a big part of me would like to see them split off to another site. I don't know if that drives away people who could potentially be power users, but don't like the high ratio of identify questions, but I’d suggest it’s a possibility.

The other point @Richard makes that I would like to echo is that for a site out of Beta, it still *feels* a little Beta-ish. The site is growing, but there's a very small group of "core" users. Meta participation is still limited to that small group of core users. I certainly expected there to be *more* core users by now. I know back when I was involved in Meta quite heavily, the key issues were definitely debated by maybe ten people, and that was it. We didn’t do a good enough job of bringing more users into that space. Given that we’re asking questions about movies, the majority of plot explanation questions are a few google searches away and answering can be a fastest gun in the west problem (which I myself fully contributed to). Quite how we overcome this, encourage new users to stay and become a part of the core community is an on-going issue that needs discussed.

On one final note, @Richard is of course wrong and the red style of the site is perfect :)

Comment: Great to see you around, Andrew. I largely agree with your and Richard's points about ID and understand your frustration; their sheer volume and rate is starting to tire even me. But it's a chicken and egg thing: The matter will never be resolved without higher participation, whether on Meta or by answering non-ID Q's and cultivating them, like you often did so well. So when we lose people like you, things are bound to get *worse*. (No pressure, though. I might have done the same if I were you. This is just how I feel.)

Comment: @Walt: Thank you for your kind comments. I hope to be around more from now on and I do hope to try and drive up some plot related questions. I supposed what drove me away was that I spent a year doing it and it felt like it made little difference. Still, it's something we can all brainstorm as a community in the weeks and months to come.

Comment: Looking at the current front page, with "identify" questions being in my "ignore" filter, I'm really starting to wonder whether "identify" questions shouldn't just get their own SE. Which of course would fail massively, since I cannot imagine anyone spending significant time there.

Comment: @BCdotWEB - The problem is that without 'identify-this' questions, Movies:SE wouldn't come close to the sorts of question numbers that justify it being a full site.

Comment: @Richard Being a full site is not about mere question numbers alone and I doubt SE would downgrade us just for abandoning ID and getting down to 5 Q/d again.

Comment: @NapoleonWilson - No, but why tempt fate?

Comment: @Richard Um, what? Eschew from trying to save the site because of supposedly "not tempting fate?". I don't really understand that attitude at all. (Besides that I know at least one SE staff member who would *highly* embrace that change anyway. And I've *never* seen a side being downgraded.)

Comment: @NapoleonWilson - I think that removing ID questions entirely is a really really (really) bad idea, nor do I think doing so would "save the site". Also, save it from what, precisely?

Comment: @Richard Sure you think that and I wasn't proposing that with this comment. However, eschewing from a major change because of supposedly "tempting fate" still seems a questionable attitude in general. (And saving from its demise, of course.)

Comment: @NapoleonWilson - I think we need to avoid falling into the trap of thinking that because *something* needs to be done, that that thing needs to be as dramatic or drastic as removing them entirely.

Comment: Also, per my point #9, I don't think we've anything like enough involvement on Meta to be able to make wise choices. If we ask the question, all we'll get is an echo chamber.

Comment: @Richard I'm not sure I agree with that attitude either, especially since *ignoring* the problem has made it *waaay* worse. Those questions have *nothing* to give to this site. But I know that not everyone might agree with this, neither might not everyone have the bigger future of the site and its wellbeing as much in mind as I do. But spare that for the respective discussion anyway.

Comment: @NapoleonWilson - Indeed. One for another day.

Comment: @NapoleonWilson: It's a real conundrum. I don't believe they offer anything to the site, and I feel a lot of users come by, ask a single question and then leave. But I'm not sure what we have to do to drive up plot explanation and other types of questions. All I do know is the *current* approach just doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: When you say *"there were (and still are) just too many [ID questions]! When I blocked them from my feed, the number of questions on a daily basis shot down"* - surely that means the problem is too few (non-ID) questions? Seems to me the high ID:non-ID ratio is a *symptom*, not a cause - and perhaps the solution is power-users like yourself asking leading by example, asking more quality questions?

Comment: @user568458: Agreed, but there doesn't have to be a single solution. We can improve non-ID questions, but why would people come here to ask and share in these questions when they are bombarded with poor quality ident questions? Instead, they take their expertise/interest elsewhere and we lose out.

Comment: For your consideration: http://meta.movies.stackexchange.com/q/2250/49

Comment: Hey hey hey, I've only been gone for like 3 years, cut me some slack!

Answer (score 14):

*Edit: Have added some graphs at bottom of post.*

***Health warning - massively long answer here. There is a Conclusion/TLDR at the bottom, although I'd advise reading the key findings first, then the conclusion/TLDR.***

I’m posting here with some information for people to digest and reflect on now that we’re a year out of Beta. I’ve chosen to post a new answer as opposed to amending my existing answer, as I’ve a lot to write here. For a lot of this answer and the metrics it provides, I’ve used [Data Stack Exchange](http://data.stackexchange.com/) which can be used to query any Stack site and unearth metrics on the questions, users and all sorts of other things.

First, I ran the following query:

```
Select count(1)
FROM posts
WHERE posttypeid = 1
```

This shows that a total of **10,348** questions have been asked in the entire history of this site.

By amending this query slightly, I can determine the amount of questions that have been tagged as “identify-this”, and the amount of questions that have not been tagged “identify this”:

```
Select count(*)
FROM posts
WHERE posttypeid = 1 and tags LIKE '%identify%'
```

This shows the following metrics:

Total identify questions: **3,061** questions (**30%** of questions ever asked)
Total non-identify questions: **7,287** questions (**70%** of questions ever asked)

However, using the following query we can break these figures down a little more by studying the trend year by year:

```
Select count(*)
FROM posts
WHERE posttypeid = 1 AND creationDate betWEEN '20100101' and '20111231' and tags LIKE '%identify%'
```

In all the queries I’ve run, I’ve simply edited the creationDate field to change the date the question was asked from 2011, to 2012, to 2013, to 2014, to 2015 and finally to 2016. These are the results:

**2011:**
Total questions: **196**
Total “identify” questions: **15 (8%)**
Total “non-identify” questions: **181 (92%)**

**2012:**
Total questions: **1421**
Total “identify”: **188 (13%)**
Total “non-identify” questions: **1233 (87%)**

**2013:**
Total questions: **2015**
Total “identify” questions: **471 (23%)**
Total “non-identify” questions: **1544 (77%)**

2014:
Total questions: **2585**
Total “identify” questions: **888 (34%)**
Total “non-identify” questions: **1697 (66%)**

**2015:** 
Total questions: **3591**
Total “identify” questions: **1249 (35%)**
Total “non-identify” questions: **2343 (65%)**

**2016:**
Total questions: **497**
Total “identify” questions: **242 (49%)**
Total “non-identify” questions: **255 (51%)**

Now, whilst 2016’s figures may look alarming, the reality is I haven’t broken down when different categories of questions are asked. In other words, it may well be the case that plot explanation questions are more popular later in the year, when summer blockbusters, or Oscar season, comes around. Regardless, the 2011 – 2015 figures show a noticeable trend, and if we take 2015, as the last complete year, as an indicator, [identify-this](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identify-this) questions comprise ~ 35% of total questions being asked on the site currently.

Now, at this point, I'm going to step away from the [identify-this](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identify-this) questions for a moment, and look at all the non-identify questions.

By editing the previous query slightly, we can reveal all the non-identify queries that have been asked in the history of the site that have been upvoted by users. In other words, all the non identify questions that have a vote score of 1 or more:

```
Select count(*)
FROM posts
WHERE posttypeid = 1 and tags NOT LIKE '%identify%' AND score > 0
```

Total non-identify questions: **7,287** questions
Total non-identify questions with a vote score of 1 or more: **6,737 (92%)**

This is a great ratio. However, again I'm going to break it down by year, by amending the above query using the CreationDate field described previously. The results are as follows:

**2011:**
Total non-identify questions: **181**
Total with upvote count > 0: **181 (100%)**

**2012:**
Total non-identify questions: **1233**
Total with upvote count > 0: **1219 (99%)**

**2013:**
Total non-identify questions: **1544**
Total with upvote count > 0: **1492 (97%)**

**2014:**
Total non-identify questions: **1697**
Total with upvote count > 0: **1570 (93%)**

**2015:**
Total non-identify questions: **2343**
Total with upvote count > 0: **2053 (88%)**

**2016:**
Total non-identify questions: **255**
Total with upvote count > 0: **190 (75%)**

Again, we could arguably disregard 2016 given how early in the year it is, but we can clear see that in the “non-identify” questions, the upvotes on the questions are going down.

This could be due to lower user participation, it could be due to higher standards on the site. I’m simply indicating a trend here and people can read into it what they believe (or use more sophisticated queries than I’m capable of to produce more information on the subject).

All in all, it suggests *to me* that for the last few years, the trend has been that the total percent of “identify-this” questions has increased, whilst the total number of non-identify-this questions deemed worthy of upvoting by the community has decreased. Whether these two things are interlinked is not clear.

At this point, I'll return to considering identify this versus non-identify this questions and I'll look at the *actual people posting these questions*. The following query shows a join between the users table and the posts table:

```
Select count(*)
FROM posts inner join users on posts.owneruserid = users.id
WHERE posttypeid = 1
```

It returns a result of **10,204**. The "users" table contains all the users active registered on the site. What this therefore means, is that out of the **10,348** questions ever asked by users, **10,204** of the questions have users who still have accounts on the site (**99**%).

I can then add a field to the query to determine how many users have more than **1 reputation point** and how many have more than **124 reputation points**:

```
Select count(*)
FROM posts inner join users on posts.owneruserid = users.id
WHERE posttypeid = 1
AND users.reputation > 1
```

By running the above query, and a slightly adjusted query with a different reputation score, I get the following results:

Total questions on the site: **10,348**
Total questions asked with users remaining on the site: **10,204**
Of the 10,204 questions asked by these users, # of askers with at least 1 reputation point: **9988 users (98%)**
Of the 10,204 questions asked by these users, # of askers with at least 125 reputation points: **6854 users (67%)**

I chose the score 124, because at 125 users can vote in elections, so I thought it might be a useful figure to determine community participation. Obviously it is a completely subjective figure and is not meant to indicate **anyone** with a lower score than that is not welcome in the community or is not part of the community. I am choosing to use it here to determine long-term participation in the site. Any user reading this with a score of < 125 - *you are truly very welcome here.*

By running a similar set of queries and specifically looking at “identify-this” and “non-identify this” questions, we can see the following:

Total identify questions ever asked: **3,061**
Total identify questions ever asked by users remaining on the site: **3,042 (99%)**
Of the 3,042 questions asked by these users, # of askers with at least 1 reputation point: **2887 (95%)**
Of the 3,042 questions asked by these users, # of askers with at least 125 reputation points: **959 users (32%)**

Total non-identify questions ever asked: **7,287**
Total non-identify questions ever asked by users remaining on the site: **7162**
Of the 7,162 questions asked by these users, # of askers with at least 1 reputation point: **7101 (99%)**
Of the 7,162 questions asked by these users, # of askers with at least 125 reputation points: **5895 users (82%)**

As you can see, participation in terms of reputation points is vastly inferior for askers of “identify this” questions compared to askers of “non-identify” questions.

More concerning to me, if we adjust the queries slightly and track this trend year-on-year, we get the following:

**2011:**
Total identify questions asked: **15**
Total identify questions asked by users remaining on the site: **15 (100%)**
Of the 15 questions asked by these users, # of askers with at least 1 reputation point: **15 (100%)**
Of the 15 questions asked by these users, # of askers with at least 124 reputation points: **15 (100%)**

Total non-identify questions asked: **181**
Total non-identify questions asked by users remaining on the site: **180 (99%)**
Of the 180 questions asked by these users, # of askers with at least 1 reputation point: **180 (99%)**
Of the 180 questions asked by these users, # of askers with at least 124 reputation points: **180 (99%)**

**2012:**
Total identify questions asked: **188**
Total identify questions asked by users remaining on the site: **186 (99%)**
Of the 186 questions asked by these users, # of askers with at least 1 reputation point: **186 (99%)**
Of the 186 questions asked by these users, # of askers with at least 124 reputation points: **147 (79%)**

Total non-identify questions asked: **1233**
Total non-identify questions asked by users remaining on the site: **1218 (99%)**
Of the 1,218 questions asked by these users, # of askers with at least 1 reputation point: **1218 (99%)**
Of the 1,218 questions asked by these users, # of askers with at least 124 reputation points: **1170 (96%)**

**2013:**
Total identify questions asked: **471**
Total identify questions asked by users remaining on the site: **469 (~100%)**
Of the 469 questions asked by these users, # of askers with at least 1 reputation point: **461 (98%)**
Of the 469 questions asked by these users, # of askers with at least 124 reputation points: **197 (42%)**

Total non-identify questions asked: **1544**
Total non-identify questions asked by users remaining on the site: **1489 (96%)**
Of the 1,489 questions asked by these users, # of askers with at least 1 reputation point: **1487 (~100%)**
Of the 1,489 questions asked by these users, # of askers with at least 124 reputation points: **1325 (89%)**

**2014:**
Total identify questions asked: **888**
Total identify questions asked by users remaining on the site: **880 (99%)**
Of the 880 questions asked by these users, # of askers with at least 1 reputation point: **833 (95%)**
Of the 880 questions asked by these users, # of askers with at least 124 reputation points: **248 (28%)**

Total non-identify questions asked: **1697**
Total non-identify questions asked by users remaining on the site: **1674 (99%)**
Of the 1,674 questions asked by these users, # of askers with at least 1 reputation point: **1668 (~100%)**
Of the 1,674 questions asked by these users, # of askers with at least 124 reputation points: **1339 (80%)**

**2015:**
Total identify questions asked: **1249**
Total identify questions asked by users remaining on the site: **1243 (~100%)**
Of the 1,243 questions asked by these users, # of askers with at least 1 reputation point: **1192 (96%)**
Of the 1,243 questions asked by these users, # of askers with at least 124 reputation points: **312 (25%)**

Total non-identify questions asked: **2343**
Total non-identify questions asked by users remaining on the site: **2311 (99%)**
Of the 2,311 questions asked by these users, # of askers with at least 1 reputation point: **2281 (99%)**
Of the 2,311 questions asked by these users, # of askers with at least 124 reputation points: **1686 (73%)**

**2016:**
Total identify questions asked: **242**
Total identify questions asked by users remaining on the site: **242 (100%)**
Of the 242 questions asked by these users, # of askers with at least 1 reputation point: **193 (80%)**
Of the 242 questions asked by these users, # of askers with at least 124 reputation points: **40 (17%)**

Total non-identify questions asked: **255**
Total non-identify questions asked by users remaining on the site: **255 (100%)**
Of the 255 questions asked by these users, # of askers with at least 1 reputation point: **232 (91%)**
Of the 255 questions asked by these users, # of askers with at least 124 reputation points: **166 (65%)**

Now, there is A LOT to take in in what I've written above. To summarise some key salient findings:

1. As the years have progressed, the askers of the majority of identify-this questions have kept their accounts active. However, they have increasingly become less involved in the site. 79% of the askers of identify-this questions in 2012 have 125 reputation points or more. Just 25% of askers of identity-this questions in 2015 have 125 reputation points or more.
2. Participation among "non-identify this" question askers appears to be contracting. 96% of the askers of non-identify this questions in 2012 have 125 reputation points or more. Just 73% of the askers of non-identify this questions in 2015 have 125 reputation points or more.

Now, I fully admit people from 2015 haven't had as long to accumulate 125 reputation points as those from 2012. However, 125 reputation points *isn't* that much, any even light users of the site can gain that amount through even semi-regular usage quite quickly.

**Summary of key findings:**

In my eyes, there is a few clear trends on the site:

Firstly, identify-this questions, whilst comprising 30% of overall questions ever asked, are becoming more numerous year on year in comparison to non-identify this questions.

Secondly, the quality of non-identify this questions is arguably dropping, based on the amount of upvotes given to them (although this is subjective and could simply be due to an increased volume of questions leading to people not having time to upvote as many questions). I believe it is the former, but acknowledge that this is subjective and others may argue differently.

Thirdly, the number of askers of identify-this questions who are active users of the site (with 125 reputation points or more) has decreased year on year, from 79% in 2012, to 25% in 2015.

Fourth, the number of askers of non-identify-this questions who are active users of the site (with 125 reputation points or more) has decreased year on year, from 96% in 2012 to 73% in 2015.

**Conclusion / TLDR**:

I love this site, even though I have been away from it for quite some time. However, I am concerned about the direction it is heading in. We don't appear to have a plan on *how* we want to drive the site forward, or the types of questions we want to see. More and more there appears to be a divide between "identify-this" and "other". I'm not sure what the solution to this is, or if anyone/everyone will agree with the many metrics I've provided here, but to me it suggests we need a site-wide decision on what sort of community we want to be, because it appears a large number of core users are unhappy about identify-this, but the metrics show the unhappiness people have towards these questions is not slowing the number of these questions being posted (rather it is increasing them).

- Do we simply ban them all?
- Do we ban all unless they provide
  certain key information (e.g. a year, a country, a genre, an actor
  description etc, even if people know the answers based without this
  key information)?
- Do we allow them all and accept the site may well
  become the web's premier haven for identify-this questions, leading
  to either a spin off movie stack site or a much smaller
  plot-explanation core on this site?

I don't know what the answer is, but I think we need to address it as the current approach doesn't *appear* to be working.

**Even shorter TL:DR**

Identify-this bad.
Other good.
*beats chest*

**Edit**:

I wanted to add some graphs for good measure. Here is the breakdown of identify this v other questions over the history of the site, with trendlines:

[image]

Here is a broken down version, showing JUST 2015 (and the first month of 2016):

[image]

As stated before, the trend isn't great, and banning them would be hard work, and would remove ~30% of the questions on the site (although I would still favour this approach).

Comment: Um, by the way, have you actually noticed [this thing](http://meta.movies.stackexchange.com/q/1890/49) already? In fact this might actually make a good answer on that question, too.

Comment: @NapoleonWilson: Nope, hadn't seen that at all! I'll add my answer there, too.

Comment: [This one](http://meta.movies.stackexchange.com/q/1987/49) might also interest you.

Comment: I'm really not sure you can generalise about the likely stats for 2016 from a single (incomplete) month.

Comment: @Richard: Agreed, and I indicated that.

Comment: Ooh graphs. Who doesn't love a graph.

Comment: @Richard: They make the whole world a little better :)

Comment: You missed a real opportunity to use a 3D graph though. Also, you forgot to click the button marked "hide filters tab", Excel-boy.

Comment: @Richard: I... no... I didn't forget. That was a deliberate design choice. For reasons.

Comment: I learned how to use Pivot Tables a few weeks ago. Now I just need to wait another twenty years for a second opportunity to use them...