# Congratulations to our moderators for a year of service

Tags: discussion

The site celebrated its [first year out of Beta](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2121/365-days-out-of-beta-where-do-we-stand) last month.

Well, [as of yesterday (17th February)](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1646/2015-community-moderator-election-results), it has also celebrated its first year of having full elected moderators.

Meta questions are always answered promptly with detailed, clear responses, moderators are almost always lurking in the chat room for discussion ([come and chat to see for yourselves](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1888)) and as the stats show you guys are still largely leading the way in terms of voting on questions and answer.

So here's a public call out to thank you for all your on-going hard work. It's been a good year and your efforts are very much appreciated.

Long may it continue!

[image]

Comment: Hmm, the appreciation is appreciated, thank you. But I feel callouts like that might be better placed in chat or as answers to questions that actually seek feedback on the moderators' performance (like [this one](http://meta.movies.stackexchange.com/q/2121/49)). Another way to salvage this question into a little more constructive direction and asking an actual question might also be to flesh it out more into asking for actual feedback on the moderators from other users. As it stands, one might be tempted to mark it as "unclear what you're asking", even if me doing so would feel a little odd.

Comment: @NapoleonWilson wow.....too much deep thoughts.

Comment: Anyways thanks for the appreciation, I hope i can give more of me to the site this year.

Comment: Wow!  It was very thoughtful and considerate for you to post this!  What an incredibly gracious gesture.  I hope you know that you are much appreciated on this site :)