# Time to say goodbye to moderator position and welcome the new blood

Tags: discussion, moderation, moderators

It's been 3 years and 8 months being a moderator here and it was really an enjoyable ride. It still feels like it was just yesterday the [announcement](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1646/2015-community-moderator-election-results) was made and I joined the team. It was nice working with [iandotkelly](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users/40/iandotkelly) and [Napoleon Wilson](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users/49/napoleon-wilson). And time to congratulate [A J](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users/27264/a-j) for joining the team and I am very much hopeful about him.

I have been thinking to quit the moderator position from many months but I was able to manage somehow. Nowadays my personal stuff keep me very much engaged and my future plans might not give me enough time to do moderation in a justifiable way. Hopefully in the future, I might try to get back to the smurfland ;) but for now, journey as muggle begins :)

I hope I didn't make anyone upset in my run and I will still be around.

Comment: Thank you for all the time you've put into the community here !!

Comment: Thank you Ankit, for everything you did.

Comment: Goodbye, friend! We all love you <3

Comment: @BlueMoon93 I am not leaving site :D

Comment: Thank you for always being helpful and nurturing. :)

Answer (score 5):

WE WILL MISS YOU BEING BLUE!!!

Sorry that this took so long to post, but I am just not able to dedicate the time to this site like I used to. I just had to post something to express my gratitude for Ankit being a super awesome moderator!

It is really weird not seeing Ankit's name in blue.  It makes me sad.  Ankit has always been welcoming and kind to everyone, especially new users.  He is really proud of this site and defends this site when he needs to.  He has made the site super fun and I am so thankful that he was a moderator when I first joined.  He was so helpful and patient in assisting me with understanding how the site works.

Thanks, buddy!  Love ya, man :)

Comment: Awww thanks a lot dear :)